# $_POST doesn't reflect data being sent with jQuery post ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using ajax/json to send values to a php function that would then display the data on the page. I'm sending two values `$hours` and `$memberID`, except I seem to only be able to retrieve `$hours` and not `$memberID`. I ran the page through Firebug, on the javascript page the values for both variables are being read right before they're sent. In the PHP form, I ran multiple conditions/echo statements to print out both values except only `$hours` is being displayed. Any ideas?

PHP:

```
$result = array();
        if(!empty($_POST['hours'])) {
            $result['type'] = "success";
            $result['memberID'] = (int)$_POST['memID'];
            $result['hours'] = (int)$_POST['hours'];
            $result = json_encode($result);
            echo $result;
         }
```

Javascript:

```
 //numberofMembers is the total number of entries in the database
function subtractHours(numberofMembers) {
document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
var hours = document.getElementById("hours");
var i = 1;
var studentID;
while(i < numberofMembers) {        
    studentID = document.getElementById("member"+i);    
    alert(studentID.value);
    if(studentID && studentID.checked) {            
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            datatype: 'json',
            url : 'hours_subtract.php',
            data : {hours : hours.value, memID : studentID.value},
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == 'success') {
                    alert('Hours subtracted!');
                } else {
                    alert('Error!');
                }
            }
        }); 
        //$.post( "subtract.php", {person: personId, personSalary: personSalary} );
    }
    i++;
}   
}
```

PHP(HTML form):

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='member{$attNumber}' id='member{$attNumber}' value=$studentID/>$attendees<br />";
```

Edit: If I run a `var_dump($_POST['memberID']);`, it prints out `NULL`. If I run a `var_dump($_POST)`, it prints out `array(2) { ["hours"]=> string(1) "1" ["member3"]=> string(8) "5101813/" }`.

Edit: I added in the PHP code that uses `member3`.
Edit 2: That's the entire Javascript function. The PHP code is all that I have for processing the data.

Comment: What happens if you do a `var_dump($_POST['memberID']);`? How about what shows in `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: where is your sql query?

Comment: Based on your edit - there's no `memberID` being sent by the ajax request. Where is `member3` coming from? I don't see that in your data. What does `memberID.value` equal in the js?

Comment: @Daniel A. White, I meant retrieving the data from the URL, the later SQL query is meant for retrieving data from the database based upon data from here.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to remove references to MySQL. This is purely an issue with PHP not getting the data you're sending

Comment: @BotskoNet, `member3` means it's the 3rd entry in the list. In the JS, `memberID.value` is 5101813

Comment: But where is `member3` coming from? I don't see that anywhere in your json data. There's some disconnect here because if you're only sending `POST ?hours=&memberID=` then PHP should reflect `$_POST['hours']` and `$_POST['memberID']`. Make a simple test case... do the ajax request to a php script that *only* dumps $_POST

Comment: You're getting a bit crazy with the edits - you now have javascript code with your PHP example. You should be reducing complexity at this stage to debug the issue, not adding more code

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to add in the line for what `member3` was being used for, and I hadn't noticed I added in the javascript into the PHP code.

Comment: My point is that `member3` is not defined in the `data: { }` object. There's no way `$_POST['member3']` would exist unless something was sending it. I think you're missing something in this example compared to what you have live.

Comment: I'm trying to change the `var_dump($_POST)` to output `["member3"]` to `["studentID"]`. How do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery Ajax, if one of the data parameters being sent is null or undefined, it will be discarded, and not sent to the server.  Since you aren't getting this property in your PHP (serverside), it's likely that it's not being set properly on the initiali client-side page.

```
memberID.value // check this value
```

Can you check that memberID.value is returning the expected value?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my site. It turns out my ajax request was not sending the data via the `$_POST` stream as I expected it would. It was actually sending it through the request body.

To access it I had to do the following:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents(“php://input”));
```

This pulled the information from the request body and decoded the json data (which is the format I sent the data to the server) into something usable by PHP. Not sure but you may be experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your example isn't really showing us the code you're using.

The following duplicates your AJAX request which is the essence of this issue:

```
$.post(
    'hours_subtract.php',
    {
        hours : "test-val-1",
        memberID : "test-val-2"
    },
    function(resp) {
        // Handle the response
    }
);
```

There are only two values being sent to the server - `hours` and `memberID`

However, you state that `var_dump($_POST)` shows:

`{ ["hours"]=> string(1) "1" ["member3"]=> string(8) "5101813/" }`

But in your ajax request, there's no such `member3`, and `memberID` isn't present in $_POST. As other have mentioned, maybe the value for memberID is null and not being sent - but that doesn't explain where `member3` comes from.

I'd suggest figuring out why you have `member3` in there, where it's coming from, and doing debug on the `memberID` value on the javascript side to find out if it's null.

Comment: what I have now shows what I'm using for `memberID`, I have no idea why it's showing up as `member3`. Can I just change it to display just text, such as `studentID`?

Comment: I suggest not proceeding with further work until you can find out why things aren't showing as you expect. Clean up the code and re-post the javascript/php as you have it if you wish. This is usually pretty straight-forward stuff, so if the $_POST contains mystery data, you need to figure out why.

Comment: I think I found it, it seems to because I set `$memberID` to `document.getElementById("member"+i);`, that's where `member3` is coming from. `i` is just a variable I'm using to parse through a list. How would I send just `i` to the PHP document?

Comment: Not quite, because PHP says the array index was `member3`, not the value. You essentially have `memberID: document.getElementById("member"+i).value` which would send `$_POST['memberID'] = "value of member+i field"`. Something is actually sending `member3` as the key.

Comment: I ran the page through Firebug, and the value I get for `memberID` is `input#member3` and then in italics is has `5101813`.

Comment: Can't I just get rid of the problem by changing the key that gets sent to the PHP document?

Comment: You're chasing the wrong problem. You never define a key called `member3` in your ajax `POST`. Where is that? Ignore your html. Ignore all other javascript. You have ajax sending values that you didn't define - so where is it coming from? I'm completely blind because you're not posting your actual code.

Comment: I bet your problem is the you have `memberID` as both a variable and a JSON member. That's why you have `member3` showing as the data key. Change the variable name and you should see `memberID` come through.

Comment: where should I change it? Sorry, I'm a struggling beginner at this

Comment: Change `var memberID` to something else, like `var memID`.

Comment: is there anyway to print out the URL? I changed the variables, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Use a web inspector for your browser, like Firebug for Firefox, to inspect the POST parameters being sent.